# with nginx with php-fpm, how do i turn off php warnings in the error log of nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

I'm running nginx with php-fpm and php 5.3.3. I have in my php.ini config

```
error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR
```

Which should turn off all php warnings in the error log but I'm still getting them. How do I get rid of them?

Comment: I'd fix the warnings. I consider them nearly as much a bug as a fatal error would be.

Comment: try to fix warning with tools like wordpress.... enjoy ;)

Answer (score 5):

I believe what you need is to modify the pool and add following:

```
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

and reload the FPM

```
sudo service php5.5-fpm restart
```

replace with whatever version you use.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

Edit your php-fpm pool configuration to specify an alternate path to log to.

An example: You can edit `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` and add something like:

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

Or you can turn logging off, but that's a really bad idea.

Comment: With the above settings, it still shows warnings in the php-fpm error log file. Seems like it overrides the entry for error_reporting given in the php.ini file.

Answer (score 2):

The setting should work.

`php-fpm` needs to be restarted as well, not only `nginx`.
Also, there are various startup (/etc/init.d/) scripts that do perform the right `kill` job when stopping `php-fpm`.

Try

```
  ps -ef | grep php
```

to get the executable name (like `php5-fpm`). Then

```
  killall php5-fpm
```

(or the name you have).

Then start php-fpm again.

*Edit 2016* On most modern unix system

```
# service php-fpm reload
```

is the right way to reload configuration (Comment from A.Gibbs)

Comment: do php assertion warnings count as errors?

Comment: Unlike the regular PHP warnings, the assertion warnings come from your *own* decision to have PHP to react on a given event. You can control this behavior using the `assert_options()` call. See http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/19/8/3

Comment: on most modern unix system '# service php-fpm reload' is the right way to reload configuration

Comment: be careful with `service php-fpm reload` on some older ubuntu systems (12.04, not sure about 14.04 yet) as reload causes php-fpm to not work correctly, you can use `service php-fpm restart` without any problems to php-fpm

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is to switch off the error reporting of php-fpm and accept the php.ini settings. In your `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

```
php_flag[display_errors] = off
```

Answer (score 0):

php_flag[display_errors] = off  did NOT work for me

In my case

php_admin_value[display_errors] = off